# Serverside redirect onClick with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, server-side-rendering

How can I perform a `Redirect` when `onClick` for server-side rendered components? The below is the component I have. When I click the button, my console.log displays but I am not redirected to the other page.

```
class UserNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);
  }

  signUp() {
    console.log('here');
    return <Redirect to="/signup" push />;
  }

  render() {
    const view = this.props.authentication ? (
      <div>test</div>
    ) : (
      <div>
        <button>Login</button>
        <button onClick={this.signUp}>Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    );
    return (<div>{ view }</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of props.

```
this.props.history.push('/signup');
```